# Postgres difference between time stamp in minutes

Tags: postgresql, time

I am trying to get time difference in minutes between the event time of below data having the same nodeid and code for nodeid having count > 1

```
nodeid  code     event_time
CAI0015 14961045 2017-04-22 21:22:00
CAI0024 14961045 2017-04-23 19:44:00
CAI0024 14961045 2017-04-23 09:07:00
CAI0040 14971047 2017-04-23 13:58:00
CAI0046 14961045 2017-04-23 11:19:00
CAI0050 14961045 2017-04-24 02:06:00
```

output should be like this:

```
nodeid  code     difference(min)
CAI0024 14961045 637
```

Comment: Please provide the expected output and what have done so far. (I.e. we need to know what difference you want to calculate: is it the actual row and the previous one's difference, or all difference where `nodeid` & `code` is the same?)

Comment: question updated, it should be the difference between all rows having the same nodeid & code

Comment: [Find difference between timestamps in seconds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14020919/2943403) divided by 60

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL: format interval as minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460805/postgresql-format-interval-as-minutes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use dense_rank to find the next event.

```
SELECT t_a.*, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (t_a.event_time - t_b.event_time))
FROM 
(SELECT nodeid, code, event_time, dense_rank() over (partition by node_id order by event_time) as rnk
 FROM table) t_a 
JOIN
(SELECT nodeid, code, event_time, dense_rank() over (partition by node_id order by event_time) as rnk 
 FROM table) t_b 
ON (t_a.nodeid=t_b.nodeid and t_a.rnk + 1 = t_b.rnk)
```

Answer (score 13):

Use the [formula `extract(epoch from <later> - <earlier>) / 60`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to get timestamp difference in minutes.

To select all permutations of differences (where `nodeid` & `code` is the same) within the table, use a self-join:

```
select nodeid, code, extract(epoch from e2.event_time - e1.event_time) / 60 difference
from   events e1
join   events e2 using (nodeid, code)
where  e1.event_time < e2.event_time
```

However, this seems not to be actually useful, when you have more than 2 rows for a given `nodeid` & `code` pair. To calculate difference for the previous ones only, use the [`lag()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
select nodeid, code, extract(epoch from event_time - lag) / 60 difference
from   (select *, lag(event_time) over (partition by nodeid, code order by event_time)
        from   events) e
where  lag is not null
```

http://rextester.com/HGY2600

*Note*: both of these will give you only one row for every `nodeid` & `code` pair, **if** you only have max 2 rows for all of the pairs.