# find the differences in minutes between two dates having timestamp?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am using `Postgres` and looking to find the differences between two dates having timestamp, how can we get the values in minutes?

> SELECT DATE_PART('sec', '2021-02-03 08:14:52'::timestamp) - DATE_PART('sec', '2021-02-03 08:17:16'::timestamp);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres difference between time stamp in minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43583952/postgres-difference-between-time-stamp-in-minutes)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=991fc37154066e022798454cbba581aa)

The difference of two `timestamp`s yields a type `interval`. You can use `EXTRACT(epoch from ...)` on intervals to receive the intervals in seconds:

```
SELECT
    extract(epoch from 
        '2021-02-03 08:17:16'::timestamp - '2021-02-03 08:14:52'::timestamp
    ) / 60
```

Divide the result by 60 gives you the minutes.

Comment: Are you sure its giving correct  values in seconds? Then divide by 60 will give correct values too?

Comment: Yes, I am :) As you can easily see in this example ( https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=10cc5589a9cac0aeb7189dd8ec42f01b ), the difference is exact 2:30min, which is the result.